# Fancybox through multiple inline DIvs

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Fancybox allows us to trigger a modal based on hidden inline HTML

```
<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
<p>Modal content 1</p>
</div>
```

But what I can't figure out is how to make several inline DIVs part of the same gallery.

Fancybox says to add rel="gallery" to images to make them part of a gallery but the same doesn't work for DIVs.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `rel="gallery"` to the anchors that trigger fancybox regardless what those anchors are targeting to (images, inline divs, etc) like :

html :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" rel="gallery">open inline 1</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" rel="gallery">open inline 2</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" rel="gallery">open inline 3</a>

<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <p>Modal content 1</p>
</div>
<div id="inline2" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <p>Modal content 2</p>
</div>
<div id="inline3" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <p>Modal content 3</p>
</div>
```

js :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    //API options
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4y1p8k9g/)**

---

On the other hand, if you just want a single anchor that triggers the full gallery instead of having an anchor for each inline `div`, then your best bet is to trigger fancybox programmatically like :

html :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#nogo">open gallery of inline divs</a>

<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <p>Modal content 1</p>
</div>
<div id="inline2" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <p>Modal content 2</p>
</div>
<div id="inline3" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <p>Modal content 3</p>
</div>
```

**Notice** we don't need the `rel` attribute because we are not grouping anchors.

js :

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function () {
    // set gallery targets
    var gallery = [{
        href: "#inline1"
    }, {
        href: "#inline2"
    }, {
        href: "#inline3"
    }];
    // triggers fancybox programmatically
    $.fancybox(gallery, {
        // API options here
    });
    return false; // prevents default and stops propagation 
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4y1p8k9g/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for this hopeful answer. But why would the second scenario repeatedly give me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $.fancybox is not a function`, even though the file is clearly loaded, and the first scenario works?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo make sure you don't have hoisting issue. The file may be loaded but not in the correct order (jQuery should be loaded before fancybox)